# Centering of figures doesn't work with SCfigure (Using TeXshop for Mac)

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, sidecap

I have a problem using `SCfigure`. I want to have my caption in the margins on the right side but the figure itself should be centered. But `\centering` doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my example (hope it works for you).
Thx

J.A.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,DIV=calc,smallheadings]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage[margincaption,outercaption,ragged,wide]{sidecap}
    \sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t} 
    \usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{SCfigure}[][ht]
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{}
    \end{SCfigure}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't a complete minimal example: The packages loaded here are probably not all necessary, and we can't run your code since the `png` file is (obviously) missing. And from which package does the `SCfigure` environment come from? Could you please provide a more concise example?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Hope it works for you now. The `SCfigure` enviroment comes from the `\usepackage[]{sidecap}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use the `floatrow` package, instead of `sidecap`. For such narrow captions, you might have interest in setting the `justification=\RaggedRight` option from the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe,outer= 6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont = sc, justification=RaggedRight]{caption}%
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[widefigure]{margins=hangright,capposition=beside,
capbesideposition={bottom, right},floatwidth=\textwidth}ASC

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{loupnorstein2}
\caption{\emph{Tale of Tales} (1979) dir. Yuri Norstein.\\ This film was awarded the title of \,‘Best animation film of all times’.}\label{norstein2}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{Hedgehog-in-the-fog}
\caption{\emph{Hedgehog in the fog} (1975) – Another film by Yuri Norstein}\label{norstein}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Works just fine with `floatrow`. But how can I get hyphenation in the `caption` to work?

Comment: What do you mean? I've just tried a longer caption, and I have hyphenation in caption.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I tried with a longer text and it worked. It is still not perfect because the space between the words is quiet large. But I think this is just because it is in the margins. Again, thanks a lot

Comment: That's typical of text in narrow columns. Try `\RaggedRight` option from the `caption` package: it allows for some hyphenation, when possible, else makes shorter lines. See my updated answer.